# Choshen HaMishpat according to Rabbeinu Bechaye

Tags: beis-hamikdash, kohen-priest, gemstone

I know that there is a  discussion about which were the stones attached to the Choshen HaMishpat. What is the opinion of Rabbeinu Bechaye about this? According to him, which were the stones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to his commentary on [Shemos 28:15](https://www.sefaria.org/Rabbeinu_Bahya%2C_Shemot.28.15.3?lang=bi&lookup=better%20known%20as%20jasper.%20It%20is%20a%20multi-colored%20gem%20consisting%20of%20red%2C%20black%2C%20green.&with=Lexicon&lang2=en):

> The names of the tribes were “inscribed chemically” each tribe’s name in accordance with the colour gemstone reflecting its individuality.

The Rabbeinu Bahya then goes on to explain what each of the gemstones it were:

> Reuven’s name was inscribed on the stone called אודם, Shimon’s on a
> stone called פטדה, etc., etc. In addition to the names of the twelve
> tribes the names of the patriarchs Avraham, Yitzchak, and Yaakov were
> also inscribed plus the words שבטי ישורון. These additional words were
> distributed between the various stones so that, for instance, the
> stone אודם with the name Reuven had an additional letter א as part of
> the name אברהם, whereas the stone פטדה which had the name שמעון
> inscribed on it also had a letter ב added as the second letter in the
> name אברהם, and so on. A stone with a short name such as גד, for
> instance, had the word שבטי of שבטי ישורון added seeing that there was
> enough space for this. The stone with the name אשר had in addition the
> letters ישר of the word ישורון inscribed on it, whereas the stone with
> the name יוסף had the last three letters of the word ישורון inscribed
> on it also, so that each stone had a total of six letters making an
> overall total of 72 letters. These 72 letters corresponded to the
> great name of the tetragram when it is spelled in all its 24
> permutations. The six days of creation comprised a total of 72 hours
> of daylight, the number of hours during which the universe and all
> that is in was created (no creation took place at night.). We know
> this as the Torah speaks of ביום עשות ה' אלו-הים ארץ ושמים (Genesis
> 2,4), “on the ‘day’ Lord G’d made earth and heaven.” This number 72
> has also been alluded to in Psalms 89,3 where David speaks about the
> world having been built on the attribute חסד, loving kindness. The
> numerical value of the word חסד is also 72. We infer from these verses
> that the world which has been created in 72 hours of creative activity
> by G’d is maintained due to the merit of the twelve tribes of Israel,
> i.e. the 72 letters inscribed in the breastplate of the high Priest.

So, Reuven's name was inscribed on a stone called אודם - Odem.

Shimeon's name was inscribed on a stone called פטדה- Pitdah (a greenish-looking gemstone, similar to the turquoise colour of the sea in certain coastal cities). The Targum Onkelos says it was a emerald.

Levi's name was inscribed on a stone called ברקת- Bareket.

Yehudah's name was inscribed on a stone called נפך- Nofeh (Onkelos also translates it as ירקן (emerald?). It is of the same group as the gemstone נפך, the stone with the name of Yehudah inscribed on it.)

Issachar's name was inscribed on a stone called ספיר - Saphire (a jewel known as sephily of a blue colour)

Zevulun's name was inscribed on a stone called  יהלום - Yahalom (his gemstone is known as pirle, same as bedolach. It is clear, transparent. It is to remind us of “white” silver, an allusion to the material wealth of the tribe of Zevulun.)

Dan's name was inscribed on a stone called לשם - Leshem (known as opal, or ashtefassis. It shows a human face turned upside down, reminiscent of the time when the tribe of Dan attempted to reverse the norms of Judaism by appointing for themselves a non-Levite as religious leader)

Naphtali's name was inscribed on a stone called שבו- Shevo (Agate. It is commonly known as turquoise.)

Gad's name was inscribed on a stone called אחלמה - Achlamah- also known as crystal.
Asher's name was inscribed on a stone called תרשיש- Tarshish (better known as cariolica, topaz, chrysolite. Its color is close to that of oil (olive oil). Others say that its color is azure-blue (compare R' David Kimchi). Onkelos translates it as כרום ימא, aquamarine. The reason is that the color of the sea resembles that of azure-blue.)

Yosef's name was inscribed on a stone called שהם - Shoham (better known as onyx)

Benjamin's name was inscribed on a stone called ישפה - Yashpeh (better known as jasper. It is a multi-colored gem consisting of red, black, green)